# sql select statement with minus zero (-0) in calculation

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Came across this bit of legacy code today.  Wondering if there is some weird and wonderful meaning to its use.  I doubt it but thought it worth checking before I remove its usage.

```
select ...
    Amount = isnull(ARTL.Amount, 0) - 0,
    Retainage = isnull(ARTL.Retainage, 0) - 0,
    DiscOffered = ARTL.DiscOffered - 0,
from tables ...
```

All three fields are numerics and the outcomes would be:

```
variable=null     0 - 0 = 0
variable=0        0 - 0 = 0
variable=-number  -number - 0 = -number
variable=+number  +number - 0 = +number
```

Comment: Are there, were there, ever any FLOATs involved? Not that I know of a reason for doing that with FLOATs, but I can imagine there might be a reason then.

Comment: I bet at one point is was used to force an implicit cast or they thought it would .

Comment: Thanks guys,  yeah I thought as much.  Code goes back to 1999 and a real dogs breakfast of changes.

Comment: If I am not mistaken this was, as @Blam said, to force that output to be a numeric field. It goes back to old d-base code. Null checks like this would result in a character field similar to a literal string return. Applying the (-0) forces it to compile as a number. Completely unnecessary in modern environments as cast and conversions are handled much more gracefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet at one point is was used to force an implicit cast or they thought it would